# How should I appropriately style a long multi-line string literal defined in a Python function?

Tags: python, coding-style

My main use-case is in unit-tests, where I want to "embed" the content of a ASCII file in a local string in order to test the operation of some function on that file content.

Currently, this is what I do:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_that_thing_with_the_file_content(self):
        test_file_cotent = """content of a ASCII text file
with multiple lines and line break, sometimes with very long lines (exceeding the usual 80 char limit, or even 120 char limit if you prefer that)
  where whitespace may be significant ...
"""
```

The problems with this approach include:

- The multi-line string breaks the indentation of the method it's defined in, which upsets me.
- Long lines can't be broken on 80-char width, which also upsets me.

The only solution I've found so far that doesn't break indentation and line-width limit is:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_that_thing_with_the_file_content(self):
        test_file_cotent = ("content of a ASCII text file\n"
                            "with multiple lines and line break, "
                            "sometimes with very long lines "
                            "(exceeding the usual 80 char limit, "
                            "or even 120 char limit if you prefer that)\n"
                            "  where whitespace may be significant ...\n"
```

But I don't like this one as well... It requires adding `\n` for every line break (which is not scalable for very long files), and it prohibits copying and pasting the actual content from an actual text file.

There's also the option to keep the string in a separate text file, and read it into a string in the code (e.g. `test_file_content = open('test_file', 'r').read()`).
The problem with this one is that the code is no longer self contained...

Is there a win-win solution that I'm missing?
Or I have no choice but to choose the trade-off that upsets me the least?

Reading PEP 8 / Google Python style guide, it seems they favor the implicit line joining approach, with explicit `\n` for every line break,
but I'd love to hear more ideas / interpretations of the style guides.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, I don't see how the claimed duplicate answers my question.

Comment: The other option is to close as mostly-opinion based. The duplicate at least shows you the available options, vs. your own reading-from-a-file approach.

Comment: Another option is to ignore the 80 character limit for that string. PEP 8 does say that *A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds*, because *Readability counts*.

Comment: But the bottom line remains: there is no One True Way here.

Comment: This isn't related to the 80 characters limit. For any limit there's an example that exceeds it. I understand there's no One True Way, so I was looking for other possible ways I might have overlooked.

Comment: I'll give you another option then: `'\n'.join(["line ..." <newline, indent> "continued line", <newline, indent> "second line ..." <newline, indent> "continued 2nd line", <etc.>])`.

Comment: That way you get to have single lines broken across source lines (auto-concatenated by the parser), the commas replace the `\n` newline literals and the `'\n'.join()` takes over for adding them back in.